Labelling subsubsections the same as equations/theorems/etc
I have the following:
\documentclass[reqno,table]{amsart}

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\begin{document}


\section{The Main Theorem}

\subsection{The statement}

\begin{theorem} All primes are even
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof} We have
\begin{equation}
p = \frac{p + p}{2} = 2 \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)
\end{equation}
is divisible by $2$.
\end{proof}

\subsubsection{The fine print}
The Theorem  only proves evenness in $\mathbf{Q}$ not in $\mathbf{Z}$, and every element in $\mathbf{Q}$ is even.

\end{document}

Which gives Theorem 1.1.1 followed by equation 1.1.2 and then subsubsection 1.1.1.
I would like instead the subsubsection to be 1.1.3, that is, I would like them to use w the same counter as equations. I can get everything else (Theorems/remarks/etc.) to be on the same counter as equations but not (yet) subsubsections.

Related/possible duplicate: Slave duplicate counter


You can make the internal count register for equations be the same as that for subsubsection
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\ExpandArgs{cc}\let{c@equation}{c@subsubsection}
\let\theequation\thesubsubsection

\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\begin{document}


\section{The Main Theorem}

\subsection{The statement}

\begin{theorem} All primes are even
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof} We have
\begin{equation}
p = \frac{p + p}{2} = 2 \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)
\end{equation}
is divisible by $2$.
\end{proof}

\subsubsection{The fine print}
The Theorem  only proves evenness in $\mathbf{Q}$ not in $\mathbf{Z}$, and every element in $\mathbf{Q}$ is even.

\end{document}

With some hyperref use you also need to reset tehH version of the counter representation:
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExpandArgs{cc}\let{c@equation}{c@subsubsection}
\let\theequation\thesubsubsection
\let\theHequation\theHsubsubsection% for hyperref <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\begin{document}


\section{The Main Theorem}

\subsection{The statement}

\begin{theorem} \label{ttt}All primes are even
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof} We have
\begin{equation}\label{eee}
p = \frac{p + p}{2} = 2 \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)
\end{equation}
is divisible by $2$.
\end{proof}

\subsubsection{The fine print}\label{sss}
The Theorem  only proves evenness in $\mathbf{Q}$ not in $\mathbf{Z}$, and every element in $\mathbf{Q}$ is even.

\ref{eee} + \ref{sss}

\end{document}


+1. Unfortunately, this is moving the goal posts, but while this works it completely breaks hyperref; links to equation 2.3.2 end up at 2.1.2 and the log file is full of error messages "pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.7.10
}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
 "

Hmm, adding back in "\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}" seemed to fix the hyperref errors.

@Lullaby ah yes as you say or simpler let theHequation to theHsubsubsection I'll add hyperref to the example later.

Oh dear. It works perfectly on my laptop at home, but at work I get "Undefined Control Sequence" for \ExpandArgs". I am using the latest TeXShop on both devices (mac) so I am very confused.

@Lullaby You have an old latex version at work, use \makeatletter\let\c@equation\c@subsubsection\makeatother which is same thing and will work in any latex since 1985/

(Confirmed that works on my post-1985 machine!)

@Lullaby I added a hyperref example
